# How does BitTorrent's use of DHT help peers find target files?

Tags: networking, bittorrent

I have read about Kademlia and understood the basic concepts of that. The basic concepts of BitTorrent are also simply understood. But both if them together make no sense at all.

From what i have been able to find online, the file hash of the target file is used to generate a target id to lookup in the DHT, then that lookup is supposed to find peers close to the target id. Okay, makes sense. Except it doesnt at all, how does the peer that has an id close to the target id happen to know anything about seeders or other peers on the network?

Any attempt to research the relevance has resulted in the same explanation that the DHT algorithm uses its Kademlianess to get to a peer whos peer id is close to the target id but this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, the 'peer with the target ID' knows about seeders or other peers because those peers also used the exact same procedure to **store** information about themselves at that location. The peer with that ID is simply a location that all other peers agree upon, to store/retrieve data related to something or other.

---

DHT is a "Distributed Hash Table", where the "[hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)" means a data structure that stores {key⇒value} mappings (also called a dict, an associative array, a lookup table, etc). A program that uses a hashtable can **put(key, value)** and the hashtable stores the {key⇒value} information at address X; then a different part of the program can **get(key)** and the hashtable retrieves the value from address X.

When a typical hashtable is used inside of a program, it would use a similar procedure to generate a memory location for a given lookup key when it's stored (the hash), and do the same when it needs to be retrieved. Databases, filesystems, Git, etc. also do the same at various levels; e.g. Git's .git/objects/.

DHT is the same, only at network level (the "distributed" part). Although BitTorrent's DHT knows some BT-specific things, fundamentally it still just stores data that BitTorrent clients need to store at an agreed-upon location. As the Kad specification says:

> To store a <key, value> pair, a participant locates...

Which means that in general terms, it can be integrated into a file-sharing protocol like this:

1. Source node S (which has the file) computes the ID and sends out a "Store" operation via the DHT network, storing the information {key: fileID ⇒ value: "available at node S"} which goes to whatever node X is closest for the key (fileID).
2. The information {key: fileID ⇒ value: "available at node S"} is then stored at node X.
3. Another peer/client node C learns the ID for the file, and sends out a "Retrieve" operation via the DHT network, which retrieves the value "available at node S" from node X.

The [BitTorrent DHT](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html) is implemented in a similar way to that example, only the "store" operation is called `announce_peer`, and it doesn't overwrite the value completely but only adds the announcer's data to the already stored list of peers.